# How to rediect to home page after login in angular, not working beow code aas it shoud be

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, authentication

in this line of code

```js
this.router.navigate(['/login'],{queryParams:{returnUrl:state.url}});
```

shows an error as "Property 'url' does not exist on type '(name: string, styles: AnimationStyleMetadata"
below is

```js
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
    import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
    import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
    import { Router, RouterLink, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
    import { startAfter } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
    import { state } from "@angular/animations";
    
    
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 
    
    export class AuthService {
      user$: Observable<firebase.User|null> | undefined;
    
      constructor(private afAuth:AngularFireAuth, private router:Router) {
        this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
       }
      login() {
        this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new GoogleAuthProvider());
      }
      logout(){
        this.afAuth.signOut();
      }
      isLoggedin(){
        this.user$?.subscribe(user =>{
          if(user) return true;
    
          this.router.navigate(['/login'],{queryParams:{returnUrl: state.url}});
          return false;
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `state`, which you imported from `animation` module, and it does not have the `url` property.

Instead of `state.url`, you should use `this.router.url`:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/login'],{queryParams:{returnUrl: this.router.url});
```

Comment: not working properly

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: same not working as it should be but not showing error even